# Is it possible to associate a concrete value with a field at compile-time?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm not sure how to phrase this exactly. I have a class, called BoundedString, which basically looks like:

```
Public Class BoundedString

    Public Property Value() As String
    Public Property MinLength() As Integer
    Public Property MaxLength() As Integer

End Class
```

Elsewhere in my code, I want to be able to say:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Property StringField() As BoundedString(Of 3, 5)
End Class
```

Where 3 and 5 represent the values of MinLength and MaxLength.

This way, I can statically specify info about my string. The closest thing I've found to this seems to be generics or maybe attributes, but I don't think generics let you specify concrete values. Is anyone aware of a language feature for doing this?

Comment: It sounds like you want attributes for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I accomplished this using attributes. The code works by:

1. Defining a set of attributes, `MinLengthAttribute` and `MaxLengthAttribute`, which can be used on fields or properties.
2. Defining a method, `GetPropertyAttribute`, which retrieves an attribute from a property on an object.
3. Using `GetPropertyAttribute` to retrieve the minimum and maximum length of the `BoundedString` when constructing it.

This allows you to associate the lengths directly next to the property, which makes the class definition fairly easy to read. Having to use `GetPropertyAttribute` to retrieve the Min/Max length values is a bit wonky though, admittedly.

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field Or AttributeTargets.Property)>
Public Class MinLengthAttribute : Inherits Attribute
    Public Property MinLength As Integer

    ''' <param name="minimumLength">The minimum length of this field/property.</param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal minimumLength As Integer)
        minimumLength = minimumLength
    End Sub
End Class

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field Or AttributeTargets.Property)>
Public Class MaxLengthAttribute : Inherits Attribute
    Public Property MaxLength As Integer

    ''' <param name="maximumLength">The maximum length of this field/property.</param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal maximumLength As Integer)
        MaxLength = maximumLength
    End Sub
End Class

''' <summary>
''' Gets the attribute TAttribute of the property <paramref name="strPropertyName" /> on this class.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="TAttribute">The type of the attribute to retrieve.</typeparam>
''' <param name="oObj">An object that has a property named <paramref name="strPropertyName"/>.</param>
''' <param name="strPropertyName">The property to get an attribute from.</param>
''' <remarks>
''' Requires that <paramref name="strPropertyName"/> has only one attribute
''' of type TAttribute. Throws an exception if this is not the case.
''' </remarks>
<Extension>
Public Function GetPropertyAttribute(Of TAttribute As Attribute)(oObj As Object,
                                                                 ByVal strPropertyName As String) As TAttribute
    Dim piPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo = oObj.GetType().GetProperty(strPropertyName)
    Dim aobjAttributes As Object() = piPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(True)

    Dim lstAttributes As List(Of TAttribute) = (From objAttribute As Attribute In aobjAttributes.OfType(Of TAttribute)()
                                                Select CType(objAttribute, TAttribute)).ToList()

    If lstAttributes.Count = 1 Then
        Return lstAttributes(0)
    Else
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Property " & strPropertyName & " has " & lstAttributes.Count &
                                            " attributes of provided type. GetPropertyAttribute requires that" & strPropertyName &
                                            " only has one property of the provided type.")
    End If

End Function

Public Class SomeClass
    <MinLength(0)>
    <MaxLength(30)>
    Public Property String1 As BoundedString

    <MinLength(5)>
    <MaxLength(10)>
    Public Property String2 As BoundedString

    <MinLength(0)>
    <MaxLength(100)>
    Public Property String3 As BoundedString

    Public Sub New(ByVal string1 As String,
                   ByVal string2 As String,
                   ByVal string3 As String)
        String1 = New BoundedString(string1,
                                    GetPropertyAttribute(Of MinLengthAttribute)("String1").MinLength,
                                    GetPropertyAttribute(Of MaxLengthAttribute)("String1").MaxLength)
        String2 = New BoundedString(string1,
                                    GetPropertyAttribute(Of MinLengthAttribute)("String2").MinLength,
                                    GetPropertyAttribute(Of MaxLengthAttribute)("String2").MaxLength)
        String3 = New BoundedString(string1,
                                    GetPropertyAttribute(Of MinLengthAttribute)("String3").MinLength,
                                    GetPropertyAttribute(Of MaxLengthAttribute)("String3").MaxLength)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. @Muhammed's answer would work I think, but my reasoning is that:

With Muhammed's answer, I have to add the value.MinLength/MaxLength = 3/5 check to the setter of every property in every class I have. This would work, but get tedious, and possibly error-prone.

With this solution, the code basically just retrieves the value of an attribute, and uses that for the min/max length. Still a bit tedious, but I'm thinking less error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

May be you need to redefine the `New()` method :

```
Public Class BoundedString

    Public Property Value As String
    Public Property MinLength As Integer
    Public Property MaxLength As Integer

    Public Sub New(myMinLength As Integer, myMaxLength As Integer)
        MinLength = myMinLength
        MaxLength = myMaxLength
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SomeClass

    Dim _StringField As BoundedString
    Public Property StringField As BoundedString
        Get
            Return _StringField
        End Get
        Set(value As BoundedString)
            If value.MinLength = 3 AndAlso value.MaxLength = 5 Then
                _StringField = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I'm not sure this does exactly what was asked. I think the intention is that the value of the StringField property can **only** be a BoundedString object with MinLength of 3 and MaxLength of 5. To ensure that you could have code in the StringField setter that thows an exception if the MinLength/MaxLength properties are not correct. But this would be a runtime check and not a compile time check.

Comment: Right, this is close - I was considering doing this. I think this'll later let you do this though, which I'm trying to avoid: SomeClass.StringField = New BoundedString(3, 6).

Going to do some research on attributes soon and write up an answer on that if it works.

Comment: @Blackwood Sorry .. it's my bad, and I am not sure if I understand what you did say, anyways .. do you suggest to delete this answer?

Comment: @Muhammad: I'm not suggesting that you delete your answer, I think this may be the closest it is possible to get to an answer. I do suggest that you update the StringField property so that in the Set clause you check that the value that the property is being set to has a MinValue of 3 and a MaxValue of 5.

Comment: @DanielNeel If your StringField property is readonly, it'll prevent people from doing SomeClass.StringField = New BoundedString(3, 6)